# How to get equations of fluid flow velocity with vorticies

Tags: fluid-dynamics, visualization

I am looking for the equation of the velocity field $\textbf{u} = u(x,y)\hat{i} + v(x,y)\hat{j}$ of a two-dimensional steady flow, which streamlines look similarly to this image: [example image of the desired streamlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYhwn.jpg).

The streamlines do not need to look exactly like the provided image, but I am looking for something that follows basic idea behind it (a bunch of differently sized vorticies scattered randomly with nice smooth flow between them).

So far I have found the equation $\textbf{u} = (0.1x^3 + y)\hat{i} + (-\sin{x} + \cos^2{x})\hat{j}$, which streamlines look like this: [one vortex streamlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uMts.png).
It looks good, but there is only one vortex and not much happening around it.

From my fluid dynamics classes, I remember I can create an initial/boundary value problem for Euler/Bernoulli equation, but it appears like a too complex solution for a seemingly simple problem.

How can I derive the equation that satisfies my conditions in an simpler way or is there already a solution to this or similar problem?

Comment: You could develop a vector field of the form $$F(x,y)=\Big<-f_y(x,y),f_x(x,y)\Big>$$ where $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables which possesses local extrema at your vortices. The flow of this vector field will have the same appearance as a contour plot of $f$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling That's perfectly what I need. I can now use Gaussian function to generate local extrema and then turn it into a vector field. Thanks

Comment: No problem. You can also multiply this $F(x,y)$ by any $\lambda(x,y)$ to generate another vector field possessing the desired flow chart.